# Pulling list item data through to a new view created by the scope data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

Although there are a few of these questions rocking about, none of them seem to have a good working example and i cant seem to figure out how to apply it to my project.

What i want to do is pull the data through from the list item into another view to use as a profile page.

**JS**

```
 var app = angular.module('passDataDemo', ['ngRoute']);

 // Configure our routes
 app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  // Route for the global controller
  .when('/', {
 templateUrl: 'list.html'
 })

 // Route for profile
 .when('/:item.firstname', {
 templateUrl: 'listItemProfile.html'
  })

  // Fallback
  .otherwise({
 redirectTo: '/'
 });

 }]);


 // Main controller
 app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

 $http.get('items.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.items = data;
 });

 }]);
```

**View 1 html**

```
 <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
 <li>
 <p>{{item.firstname}}</p>
  <p>{{item.surname}}</p>
<button ng-click="viewTheProfileView()">View Profile</button>
```

**View 2 html**

```
 <h1>ITEM PROFILE</h1>
<p>{{item.firstname}}</p>
<p>{{item.surname}}</p>
```

Here is my Plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/gZj5gOZEcCOLNbdxwduw?p=preview

Comment: this is not angular, this is angularJS, please update the tags.
AngularJS => version 1 of angular.
Angular => Version 2+ of angular.

Comment: You can create a service to share data between two of you controllers for different views.

Comment: I've tried to do this but couldn't quite get it working. How would i do this with my Plunker set up?

Comment: Lots of different ways to set this up. [Here is one example](https://plnkr.co/edit/sCiLBfA1sCf7AXttgpZL?p=preview) using a service and different controllers for each route and using`$routeParams` in url. Strongly suggest you study some routing tutorials

Comment: Thanks very much @charlietfl, this was exactly what i was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your plunker, I see that you are only using one controller for all of your views. Because of this, you would only need to set the value of `$scope.item` and it will show up in your `listItemProfile.html`. Therefore, I would change your button to pass in the current `item` to the controller: `<button ng-click="viewTheProfileView(item)">View Profile</button>`.

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.viewTheProfileView = function(item) {
    $scope.item = item;
};
```

This will allow clicking the `ITEM PROFILE` button in `index.html` to display the correct information.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. How would i go about creating the view based on the name data such as /Roger.html? Kind of like it creates a new view based on the list item clicked. Hope that makes sense!